# Ajax done() and always() never fire in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
function getLicenseCount() {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: LFLicenseCheckerURI,
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data) {
        updateRemainingLicenses(data);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        alert("Unable to get remaining license count.");
    }).always(function(data) {
        $loadingScreen.hide();
    });
}
```

The server returns a simple number in text format, which is why DataType is set to text.

I am calling this function inside a self-invoking function expression further up on the page:

```
(function() {   

    console.log("before");
    getLicenseCount();
    console.log("after");

    //other stuff

}());
```

This works fine in Chrome, IE and Edge. However, in Firefox, it gets stuck somewhere and the `console.log("after")` never fires. No errors are reported. What is even more bizarre is that the `always` promise function doesn't fire either! If I put another `console.log` inside that, it doesn't get displayed in Firefox, but works fine in other browsers.

Anyone have thoughts on what could be happening here?

Comment: There's no obvious reason why this code should fail from looking at it. Try turning on "pause on exceptions" in the firefox developer tools (I'm assuming that feature exists). Also check the network tab to make sure the request isn't being blocked.

Comment: Why was I downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It's because my self-invoking function expression was located **before** the function definition for `getLicenseCount()`. It seems Chrome's JS engine is smart enough to figure things out when stuff is out of order, but Firefox's isn't. Changing the order of the two blocks made it work.

I only discovered this by accident when I changed the way I defined the function from `function getLicenseCount()` to `var getLicenseCount = function()`. Chrome then threw an error saying GetLicenseCount is not a function. Firefox was still quiet about it though!